# Rename level in multiindex/multilevel Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `DataFrame` like this:

```
arrays = [np.array(['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux']),
          np.array(['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two']),
          np.array(['2016-01', '2016-02', '2016-01', '2016-02', '2016-01', '2016-02', '2016-01', '2016-02'])]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.ceil(np.random.randn(8, 4)), index=arrays)

df.rename(columns={0:'m1',1:'m2',2:'m3',3:'m4'},inplace=True)

                  m1   m2   m3   m4
bar one 2016-01 -0.0  1.0  3.0  2.0
    two 2016-02  1.0  1.0  1.0  2.0
baz one 2016-01 -1.0 -1.0  2.0  1.0
    two 2016-02  1.0  2.0  1.0  2.0
foo one 2016-01  1.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0
    two 2016-02 -2.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0
qux one 2016-01 -0.0 -0.0 -1.0  1.0
    two 2016-02 -0.0 -0.0  1.0 -0.0
```

Let's say I want to replace all 2016 for 2017 in the column name for m2 and m4 so that the 2016 rows will have values for m1 and m3 but not for m2 and m4. And so the 2017 rows will have values for m2 and m4 but not m1 and m3. Something similar to this `DataFrame`:

```
                  m1   m2   m3   m4
bar one 2016-01 -0.0  0.0  3.0  0.0
    two 2016-02  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
    one 2017-01  0.0  1.0  0.0  2.0
    two 2017-02  0.0  1.0  0.0  2.0
baz one 2016-01 -1.0  0.0  2.0  0.0
    two 2016-02  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
    one 2017-01  0.0 -1.0  0.0  1.0
    two 2017-02  0.0  2.0  0.0  2.0
```

I've tried to `unstack()` the dataframe and rename each column but that doesn't seem to work and I'm not sure why.

```
df = df.unstack()
df.unstack()['m2'] = df.unstack()['m2'].rename(columns = lambda t: t.replace('2016','2017'))
```

Comment: Sorry I did that to make the example smaller. I just want to change the dates on some measures and then add those to the index. That why `[baz,[one, two]]` repeat but the dates are different.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(2017)

arrays = [np.array(['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux']),
          np.array(['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two']),
          np.array(['2016-01', '2016-02', '2016-01', '2016-02', '2016-01', '2016-02', '2016-01', '2016-02'])]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.ceil(np.random.randn(8, 4)), index=arrays)

df.rename(columns={0:'m1',1:'m2',2:'m3',3:'m4'},inplace=True)

df2 = df[['m2', 'm4']]
df2.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(
    [df.index.get_level_values(i) for i in [0,1]]
    + [df.index.get_level_values(-1).str.replace('2016','2017')])

result = pd.concat([df[['m1','m3']], df2], axis=0).fillna(0)
result = result.sort_index(level=[0,2,1])
print(result)
```

converts

```
                  m1   m2   m3   m4
bar one 2016-01 -1.0 -0.0  1.0  1.0
    two 2016-02 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0
baz one 2016-01  1.0 -0.0 -1.0 -0.0
    two 2016-02 -1.0  1.0  1.0 -0.0
foo one 2016-01 -0.0 -0.0 -1.0 -1.0
    two 2016-02  2.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0
qux one 2016-01  1.0  2.0 -0.0  2.0
    two 2016-02  1.0  1.0 -0.0 -0.0
```

into

```
                  m1   m2   m3   m4
bar one 2016-01 -1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
    two 2016-02 -0.0  0.0 -0.0  0.0
    one 2017-01  0.0 -0.0  0.0  1.0
    two 2017-02  0.0 -0.0  0.0 -0.0
baz one 2016-01  1.0  0.0 -1.0  0.0
    two 2016-02 -1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
    one 2017-01  0.0 -0.0  0.0 -0.0
    two 2017-02  0.0  1.0  0.0 -0.0
foo one 2016-01 -0.0  0.0 -1.0  0.0
    two 2016-02  2.0  0.0 -0.0  0.0
    one 2017-01  0.0 -0.0  0.0 -1.0
    two 2017-02  0.0 -0.0  0.0 -0.0
qux one 2016-01  1.0  0.0 -0.0  0.0
    two 2016-02  1.0  0.0 -0.0  0.0
    one 2017-01  0.0  2.0  0.0  2.0
    two 2017-02  0.0  1.0  0.0 -0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I quite understand your question, here is what i did and the output.

```
    arrays = [np.array(['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux']),
          np.array(['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two']),
          np.array(['2016-01', '2016-02', '2016-01', '2016-02', '2016-01', '2016-02', '2016-01', '2016-02'])]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.ceil(np.random.randn(8, 4)), index=arrays)

df.rename(columns={0:'m1',1:'m2',2:'m3',3:'m4'},inplace=True)
df = df.reset_index()
df['level_2'] = df['level_2'].str.replace("2016","2017")
```

Which gives me the output:

```
level_0  level_1  level_2  m1  m2  m3  m4

0   bar    one    2017-01 -0.0 -1.0 -0.0 -0.0
1   bar    two    2017-02 -0.0  -1.0 2.0  2.0
2   baz    one    2017-01  -2.0 1.0 -0.0  1.0
3   baz    two    2017-02  -0.0 1.0 -1.0  2.0
4   foo    one    2017-01  1.0  -0.0 -1.0 -0.0
5   foo    two    2017-02  -1.0 -2.0  1.0 -0.0
6   qux    one    2017-01   1.0 1.0  -0.0  1.0
7   qux    two    2017-02   1.0 -1.0  2.0 -1.0
```

If you could let me know what you are expecting based on this, I will modify my answer.

Comment: Yeah I don't think I'm explaining myself right. For example, your `level_2` should have a mixture of 2016 and 2017 dates depending on the column name. Right now my `df` has all 2016 dates. But some of those dates are actually 2017. I kept it this way in order to ease the calculations but now that I have my results I want to change those to 2017. I guess another way of looking at this would be like: How can you change level_2 to 2016 for only `m1`. That means that `m2...m4` will have remain unchanged but the `df` will have extra rows with values only in `m1`

Comment: "some of those dates are actually 2017. I kept it this way in order to ease the calculations but now that I have my results I want to change those to 2017" -- Whoa! That sounds like a really brittle way to get results! Perhaps you should reframe the question about how to efficiently do the analysis on correctly-dated records?

Comment: I agree. You need to change your question.